# Faience theme 12.10

Tags: 12.10, themes

I'm trying to install the faience theme in ubuntu 12.10 with unity. I installed it from the ppa, then tried to use Unsettings to apply it.

I can apply all of the themes except for the window themes. The GTK and icon themes work fine.

Anybody have this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comment on the [deviantART theme page](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/GTK3-Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456?) explains how to fix this. It appears to be caused by the file `metacity-1/metacity-theme-2.xml`. You can either remove it or rename it:

```
 cd /usr/share/themes/Faience/metacity-1 # Or ~/.themes/Faience/metacity-1 if you installed it by hand
 sudo mv metacity-theme-2.xml metacity-theme-2.xml-OLD
```

This will allow you to set the Faience window theme.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue preventing me from correctly applying the theme. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue.

It's been fine up until now - I expect something broke in the latest release.

I would report any issues here:
http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/GTK3-Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456

Update:
Just discovered. It works if you select 'Faience-Ocre' as your theme, rather than if you select 'Faience' it works properly.