# Ubuntu showing Old Gui

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gui, elementary

I was trying to install DraftSight and It was showing some error. So to solve that error I installed the following two packages using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libglib2.0-dev
```

After this my panel started showing old kind UI. You can compare between two images.
Before
[image: The original ui]
And after
[image: Ui after installing packages]

So I removed the above packages immediately (replaced install with remove in the above command) and rebooted. After rebooting the there were no panel and titlebars to windows. So I reinstalled compiz using the below command

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install compiz
```

and rebooted. The title bar and panel appeared after that. But still it was showing the old GUI. I tried removing libglib2.0-0:i386 package as I saw two versions of libglib package But still not effect. Please help

I am using Elementary OS (12.04) 64bit

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Firstly I thought that it was because some packages like libglib or libgtk. But the problem was because of somehthing else. I also had problem with the animation and windows border. I wasn't able to switch between windows. To solve this problem you just have to reinstall compiz using the command given in the question

[Fixing theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230845/faience-theme-12-10)

Look at the above link and follow the instructions. It is a solution for Faience theme but same can be applied for elementary theme.

```
cd /usr/share/themes/elementary/metacity-1

~/.themes/elementary/metacity-1 if you installed it by hand

sudo mv metacity-theme-3.xml metacity-theme-3.xml-OLD
```

If you rename the metacity file you will be able to change the GTK theme using Ubuntu Tweak  which will make your panel whose image I have shared in the question look normal but elementary window theme may not work.

For the window theme to work firstly reboot and theme change the same metacity file to normal i.e remove the "-OLD"

```
sudo mv metacity-theme-3.xml-OLD metacity-theme-3.xml
```

and then try changing the window theme using Ubuntu Tweak. It will restore everthing back to normal. If this doesn't work. there here are some link you can look into.

[Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=compiz%20ubuntu%20showing%20old%20gui&oq=compiz%20ubuntu%20showing%20old%20gui&aqs=chrome..69i57.7185j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8#q=cannot%20change%20theme%20gtk)
[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361335/ubuntu-gnome-13-10-cannot-change-window-border-theme)
[Ask Ubuntu 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62495/how-to-change-the-window-theme-in-gnome-shell)

Cheers!