# Title bars no longer responsive to GTK themes

Tags: unity, themes, gtk

In Ubuntu 16.04, I have a lovely Solarized theme. Previously it made my title bars a nice dark blue and replaced the orange and grey Unity-themed icons with something more subtle. But today, upon logging in, I found the old Unity grey and orange title bars again.

Currently my title bars all look like this:
[image]

But when I first set the theme, they all looked like this:
[image]

The Unity glare boxes have also returned to the launcher as you can see in my screenshots.

I have already taken the advice of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230845/faience-theme-12-10) but nothing changed. Any ideas on how to return my theme to its prior glory?

Comment: Try re-setting your good theme from Unity Tweak?

Comment: I did that- the problem is that no matter what theme I change it to, the title bars remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting lightdm fixes this in the short term. I don't know the cause, and it happens almost every time the display is changed. Perhaps this is a bug in Unity Tweak Tool.